# Rails: undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How exactly do I create separate pages while still able to user info from controller and model?

For example, I want to have separate pages but still using the same info from the products controller.

views/product/**order.html.erb**

Yet when I add a simple_form_for I get an error

```
<%= simple_form_for(@products) do |f| %>
```

Basically all I'm trying to have is a separte page to submit info for the product. If not I'd gladly be happy to do it within the same page and have a revolving simple_form like this without having to create multiple pages.

http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/

Example:

[image: Example-1]
[image: Example-2]
[image: Example-3]

**products_controller.rb**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
@products = Product.where(availability: true)
  respond_with(@products)
end


def show
end


def new
  @product = Product.new
end


def edit
  authorize! :manage, @product
end


def create
    @product = current_user.products.new(product_params)
  @product.save
  respond_with(@product)
end


def update
    authorize! :manage, @product
  respond_to do |format|
    if @product.update(product_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def destroy
    authorize! :manage, @product
  @product.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Product was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

Comment: paste your controller code

Comment: Are you sure its `@products` in `<%= simple_form_for(@products) do |f| %>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= simple_form_for(@product) do |f| %>
```

Use @product instead of @products

Add following to products_controller.rb

```
def order
  @product = Product.new
end
```

Comment: I'm still getting `undefined method model_name for nil:NilClass`, I have updated an example in the question. How do I do that without having to create a new page, like allow the form to just slide by pressing the bubbles at the top?

Comment: where is your method **order** has defined in your products_controller?

Comment: I have not defined order, I just thought of a random page

Comment: Try `resources :products` in your congig/routes.rb